# Rails Ordering considering two attributes at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called List and each list has many Car. Each car has a driver, that can be a registered driver or not. This is how a retrieve a driver's name

```
Car Draper Decorator:
...
def driver_name
  if driver.present?
    driver.name
  else
    model.driver_name
  end
end
```

Ok, now I want to order a List by the name of the car's drivers. Which means that when running List.cars would return a list ordered by the name of the drivers considering both registered and non registered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby's sort method - rather than active record:

```
cars = Car.all
sorted_cars = cars.sort{|a,b| a.decorate.driver_name <=> b.decorate.driver_name }
```

This will use your decorator method defined to do the sorting.